# How to change the permalink option to post name on theme activation?

Tags: permalinks, filters

Is there any filter to change the permalink structure and set it to post name after theme activation automatically?

i have custom posts but won't work without changing the permalink?

thanks

Comment: Why do your custom post types not work without changing permalink structure? Maybe solve that problem instead?

Comment: hmm because custom post get generated like - www.website.com/custom-post-type/the-page-under-custom post   but is the permalink structure is different means after saving the post the url becomes like -www.website.com/1212sax2

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla is possible that you custom post are not properly registered.

Comment: i used the same method as mentioned in the wordpress codex..whether permalink for the custom post works even if the permalink structure is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flush rewrite rules to be considered while when custom posts are generated.

More info here 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

This worked for me as when my theme is activated every thing works file

```
/* Flush rewrite rules for custom post types. */
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'flush_rewrite_rules' );
```